# Помогите поправить код на Python, который удаляет последний пост в Телеграм канале

Tags: python, telegram

Доброго времени суток!

Пытаюсь написать код на python, который удаляет последний пост из моего Телеграм канала.
Вроде все верно пишу, на первый взгляд, но код не работает...

Помогите исправить, пожалуйста!

```py
import asyncio
from telegram import Bot
from telegram.error import TelegramError

bot_token = '12345ertertert'
chat_id = '@ertgsg54g4'


async def main():
    bot = Bot(token=bot_token)

    try:
        messages = await bot.get_chat(chat_id).fetch_all()

        if messages:
            message_to_delete = messages[-1]
            await message_to_delete.delete()
            print(f'Успешно удалили сообщение: {message_to_delete.text}')
        else:
            print('В канале нет сообщений для удаления.')
    except TelegramError as e:
        print(f'Произошла ошибка: {e}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

При запуске этого кода, появляется ошибка:

```
D:\pyMap\venv\Scripts\python.exe "D:\pyMap\main 5.py" 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pyMap\main 5.py", line 29, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "C:\Users\777\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 194, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\777\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\777\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 664, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\pyMap\main 5.py", line 15, in main
    messages = await bot.get_chat(chat_id).fetch_all()
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'fetch_all'
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Bot.get_chat' was never awaited

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Что означает "не работает"?

Comment: @Эникейщик , прошу прощения, я добавил ошибку, которая появляется